# base 64 URL decode with Ruby/Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, encoding, base64

I am working with the Facebook API and Ruby on Rails and I'm trying to parse the JSON that comes back. The problem I'm running into is that Facebook base64URL encodes their data. There is no built-in base64URL decode for Ruby.

For the difference between a base64 encoded and base64URL encoded, [see wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications).

How do I decode this using Ruby/Rails?

**Edit**:

Because some people have difficulty reading - base64 URL is DIFFERENT than base64

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Googling for "base64 for URL ruby" and choosing the first result lead me to [the answer](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/167232#734261)

> ```
>  cipher_token = encoded_token.tr('-_','+/').unpack('m')[0]
> ```
>
> The details of the cipher_token aren't
>   important save that it can contain any
>   byte values.

You could then, of course, make a helper to `base64UrlDecode( data )`.

What's happening is that it takes the `encoded_token` and replaces all the `-` and `_` characters with `+` and `/`, respectively. Then, it decodes the base64-encoded data with `unpack('m')` and returns the first element in the returned array: Your decoded data.

Comment: yea, i saw this http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/167232, but it wasn't my first result. second page for me.. anyway. I don't understand what that actually does... I need to go the OTHER way

Comment: I thought you wanted to decode the data that Facebook is sending you... ? In the example above, `encoded_token` is what Facebook is sending to you and `cipher_token` is the decoded result.

Comment: You may get a malformed JSON error with this solution due to the way padding is handled. See http://qugstart.com/blog/ruby-and-rails/facebook-base64-url-decode-for-signed_request/ for the solution.

Answer (score 13):

Dmitry's answer is correct. It accounts for the '=' sign padding that must occur before string decode. I kept getting malformed JSON and finally discovered that it was due to the padding. [Read more about base64_url_decode for Facebook signed_request](http://qugstart.com/blog/ruby-and-rails/facebook-base64-url-decode-for-signed_request/).

Here's the simplified method I used:

```
 def base64_url_decode(str)
   str += '=' * (4 - str.length.modulo(4))
   Base64.decode64(str.tr('-_','+/'))
 end
```

Comment: I believe it is only legal to pad by 1 or 2, not by 3 or 4. e.g. if str.lenght.modulo(4) is zero, then don't pad. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: Note: Padding with four '=' seems to break if you use strict_decode64 or urlsafe_decode64, but is tolerated by decode64.

Answer (score 5):

For base64URL-encoded string `s`...

```
s.tr('+/', '-_').unpack('m')[0]
```

Comment: maybe... what's it do? I'm fairly good at ruby, but you've got me beat.

Comment: It transliterates `+` to `-` and `/` to `_`, which should yield plain base64, and then it uses the built-in base64 unpacker, which returns, I think, a one-element array, so we grab the actual string result with `[0]`. You could replace `[0]` with `.first`

Comment: It looks like you can also go the other way and convert a base64-encoded string to base64URL with `s.tr('-_', '+/')`

Answer (score 3):

That's the way i parse the signed_request of my facebook application

```
def decode_facebook_hash(signed_request)
  signature, encoded_hash = signed_request.split('.')
  begin
    ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(Base64.decode64(encoded_hash))
  rescue ActiveSupport::JSON::ParseError
    ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(Base64.decode64(encoded_hash) + "}")
  end
end
```

The rescue part only add a '}', becouse facebook is weird enough to let it out of de encoded hash sometimes (maybe they fixed it already...).

Answer (score 2):

```
def decode64_url(str)
  # add '=' padding
  str = case str.length % 4
    when 2 then str + '=='
    when 3 then str + '='
    else
      str
  end

  Base64.decode64(str.tr('-_', '+/'))
end
```